# Parsing data in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to write a query against a SQL Server database that parses the data in a column.

The contents look like this:

```
.\\data\\21\\35\\1083\\
```

How would I write the query to parse out 21, 35, and 1083 into separate fields? The pattern is always `.\\data\\x\\y\\z`

I investigated `PARSENAME` and `SUBSTRING` functions, but neither seem to work.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: When you "investigated" parsename, how did you do that and why did it "not work"? Seems you simply remove the first seven characters, replace "\" with . to use parsename. And why tag both MySQL and SQL Server? And why not just use the solution to your REGEX question on the same topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2017 onwards.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('.\data\21\35\1083\');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , PARSENAME(c, 3) AS col1
    , PARSENAME(c, 2) AS col2
    , PARSENAME(c, 1) AS col3
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(TRIM('.\' FROM tokens),'\','.')) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+----+--------------------+------+------+------+
| ID |       tokens       | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+--------------------+------+------+------+
|  1 | .\data\21\35\1083\ |   21 |   35 | 1083 |
+----+--------------------+------+------+------+
```